# Building Asp.net Page code behind correctly

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I need some guidelines about building the code behind of my pages correctly. I mean, I'm building in asp.net for a year now, and mostly using the Page_Load event. (and ofcourse "event handling" the events triggered by the user's actions). I know about the page life cycle and the order of events that happens when a page is requested etc.. . Is it normal that, generally, in a data-driven page, for example, I'm not using any of the "pre_render", "page_unload", "pre_init" etc.. event handlers? or am I missing something here? any guidelines would help me a lot, including links or whatever you think that would instruct me well. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not missing anything.

Most asp.net code does not use these events, and you should only be using the handlers if you need to.

For example - if you really need to change the output of the page after all control event handlers (for example button clicks) have fired, use the `pre_render` event. In my experience this is a rare thing to need.

Many of the event are there *just in case* you need them.

Comment: @Hagai - My bad. I meant `pre_render`, not `pre_init`.

Answer (score 1):

Page_Load actually is the most used event handler in page life cycle. What i've used relatively often is Page_Init when i [added controls dynamically](http://www.csharper.net/blog/adding_controls_dynamically_to_a_page_in_asp_net.aspx) to the page(ViewState issue).

Look here for further informations:
http://www.csharper.net/blog/page_lifecycle_methods_in_asp_net_2_0.aspx